# How to merge cells in loop in vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to merge every second cell going trough columns, starting at the 12.column till last used column, but the code isn't working. Can somebody point out a mistake that I'm making?

```
For i = 13 To lCol Step 2
    Sheet9.Range(Sheet9.Cells(3, i), Sheet9.Cells(3, i + 1)).Merge
Next i
```

Comment: @pnuts Can you explain why? This is my header, it just starts in third row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `20` as a hardcoded value for last column and the code below:

```
Public Sub TetMe()

    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To 20 Step 2
        With Worksheets(1)
            .range(.Cells(3, i), .Cells(3, i + 1)).Merge
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

you will get a result like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this pushed me in the right direction and, with a little bit of adapting of your code, its now working perfectly.